# kotlin setOnClickListener not running on click

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, listener

I'm trying to add a `setOnClickListener` to a programmatically created layout, but I cannot make it work. I've seen in other questions that they have made a function with the listener on ot but didn't run it, but this is not my case.

```
for (anime in search.anime) {

                runOnUiThread {

                    var layout = LinearLayout(this)

                    AnimeResultLayout.addView(layout)

                    layout.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"))

                    layout.setOnClickListener {
                        Toast.makeText(this@SearchActivity, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                    var param = layout.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                    param.setMargins(0, getDps(5), 0, getDps(5))
                    layout.layoutParams = param

                    layout.orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL

                    var cover = ImageView(this)
                    layout.addView(cover)

                    cover.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getDps(78), getDps(111))
                    Picasso.with(this).load(anime.cover).into(cover)
                    cover.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP

                    var textlayout = LinearLayout(this)
                    layout.addView(textlayout)

                    textlayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL

                    var titletext = TextView(this)
                    textlayout.addView(titletext)

                    titletext.text = anime.title

                    textlayout.setPadding(getDps(10), getDps(10), getDps(10), getDps(10))

                    titletext.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

                    titletext.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.black))

                    titletext.textSize = 16F

                    var textlayoutbottom = ConstraintLayout(this)
                    textlayout.addView(textlayoutbottom)

                    var typelabel = TextView(this)
                    textlayoutbottom.addView(typelabel)

                    textlayoutbottom.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f)

                    typelabel.text = getAnimeType(anime.type)
                    typelabel.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

                    var params = typelabel.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
                    params.leftToLeft = textlayoutbottom.id
                    params.bottomToBottom = textlayoutbottom.id
                    typelabel.requestLayout()

                    typelabel.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.ykblue))
                }

            }
```

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ykblue"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:id="@+id/SearchText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:hint="Search"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/searchhintcolor"
            android:textColorLink="@color/white"
            app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/ResultsLayout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Animes"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:background="@drawable/home_text_drawable"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/AnimeResultLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ReportDuplicatedResults"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Report duplicated results"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_background_btn_small"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm trying to show some results on my activity and take it to another activity depending on what it clicks, but I cannot make it even toast something. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Are you adding clickable child views in your LinearLayout? they might be consuming the clicks

Comment: I've already tried to use `setOnClickListener` to the imageview but nothing happened

Comment: The same with the `textlayout`

Comment: @ChristilynArjona I've added my xml. Can you see something strange?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you passed right context and also check your XML layout some other layout above of your click listener or may be you use multiple time click listener

> layout.setOnClickListener

so please make sure it.

Comment: I've already tried setting the click listener to the imageview but it did nothing